# How to remove Thumbnail property of a JPEG image without distrubing other Exif data in C ++ .net

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have an application which edits the metadata part of the JPEG image. I have to remove the thumbnail metadata with out disturbing other metadata. I have tried out the code below but was not successful in removing thumbnail metadata. can some help me out in solving this query thanks in advance.

```
array<String^>^ query = gcnew array<String^>(4);

query[0] = "/app1/ifd/tiff:";
query[1] = "/app1/ifd/tiff/subifd:";
query[2] = "/ifd/tiff:";
query[3] = "/ifd/tiff/subifd:";

for each (String^ SetQuery in query)
{
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=256}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=257}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=258}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=259}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=273}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=262}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=277}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=278}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=279}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=282}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=283}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=284}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=296}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=513}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=514}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=529}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=530}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=531}");
 metaData->RemoveQuery(SetQuery + "{uint=532}");
}
```

Comment: I love how it's tagged C, but the title says C#, and the code is C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Would *ExifTool by Phil Harvey* at http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ help you? The Perl source is available if you need to see how it is done.